# I keep getting ("ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined") Error. Anything helps,Thank you

Tags: sql, oracle

Report all books published after Jan. 1st, 2015, as well as all books published in 2014 that have retail price of $50 or less. Show the title, publisher's number, retail price, and date published. The list should sort the data first by publisher number, then by retail price within each publisher. So you will have two sets of data in the report: all books published after January 1st, 2015 as well as those books published in 2014 that have retail price of $50 or less.

```
SELECT Title, Name, Retail, Pubdate.
FROM BOOKS, PUBLISHER
WHERE Pubdate >'01-JAN-2015'
OR
(Pubdate LIKE '%2014' AND Retail <=50)
ORDER BY PubID, Retail;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S43Wy.jpg)

Comment: Prepend each column with the table where it belongs to as in `BOOKS.Title` and problem solved.

Comment: this query is missing the join condition between BOOKS and PUBLISHER

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged